# android - how to detect a particular view has focus when user swipes finger on screen

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app similar to piano. I am unable to play sounds as the user moves his finger over various piano bars without lifting the finger. I looked at gestures but couldn't do it. 
Can anyone pls. help me.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [android - how to detect a particular view has focus when user swipes finger on screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611310/android-how-to-detect-a-particular-view-has-focus-when-user-swipes-finger-on-sc)

Answer (score 4):

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        String eventName = "";

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)v;

        for(int i =0; i< layout.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View view = layout.getChildAt(i);


            Rect outRect = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
            //Rect outRect = new Rect();                
            //view.getLocalVisibleRect(outRect);//nao funciona

            if(outRect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
            {
                //touching piano key
            }
        }
```

}

add this code to your Layout OnTouchEventListener method.
Remember: you must add Views to your Linear/Relative/Grid Layout and call (Linear/Relative/Grid).setOnTouchEventListener(OnTouchEventListener).