# How do I activate Android ToggleButtons by dragging my finger across them?

Tags: java, android, togglebutton, gestures

For school I'm making an Android application which is basically a drum pattern sequencer.

My Android application contains 64 *Toggle Buttons* which I drew programmatically in my *MainActivity.java* in *OnCreate()*.

**How I drew 16 of the 64 *Toggle Buttons*:**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (float)1.0);
    lp.width = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 0, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    int i;

    /* 16 toggle buttons for Row 0 */
    int id0;
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
        ToggleButton myButton = new ToggleButton(this);
        myButton.setText(null);
        myButton.setTextOff(null);
        myButton.setTextOn(null);
        myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.statelist);
        LinearLayout ll0 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutRow0);
        ll0.addView(myButton, lp);  
        id0 = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(110) + Integer.toString(i));
        myButton.setTag(id0);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Button Tag: " + v.getTag().toString() );
            }
        });
    }
```

**Now what I'm trying to do is:** 
Make it possible to select any or all of the 64 *Toggle Buttons* by simply dragging a finger across the screen.

**To be specific:**
The *Toggle Buttons* will initially be off, then dragging a finger across the screen will turn on all the *Toggle Buttons* I have "drawn over." After that I want to add a button in the *Action Bar* to select if dragging will turn the *Toggle Buttons* on or off but not both.

Comment: Have you looked into the android Switch View? I believe it supports sliding swipe behavior and has the same basic logic of a togglebutton.

Comment: Right, but can you slide across multiple Switches and activate them all without raising your finger from the screen by default, or would I have to implement that?

Comment: Ah I understand; maybe this link will be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597592/sliding-finger-across-screen-activating-buttons-as-if-they-were-pressed