# Detect swipe over view

Tags: java, android

I want a view to be able to detect whether the user swipes (or rather moves his/her finger) over it: Swipes should be detected no matter whether they begin inside or outside the view, same goes for the end of the touch event.

As far as I can see, adding an `OnTouchListener` on the view won't work for this kind of gesture, as `onTouch` isn't called given that the touch event starts outside the view.

Any help on that subject is highly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at gestureDetector

Comment: Since you pass the `MotionEvent` received in `onTouchEvent`, which IS NOT called when the touch didnt start inside the view, to your  `GestureDetector`, this approach does not work.

Comment: Than make the listener on the parent element and detect if the touch.getX is > view.x and < view.x + view.getWidth() .. lol really simple :D

Comment: Gaah, I'm so stupid... I shouldn't be up coding at this time ;-) But thank you anyways for your advice, It works like a charm *thumbsup*

Comment: don't forget to make this for getY as well.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this question, should have the answer for you:

[Detect which view your finger is sliding over in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838609/detect-which-view-your-finger-is-sliding-over-in-android)